# product template error in odoo v16 on the online selling website

Tags: odoo-16

UncaughtPromiseError
Uncaught Promise > Missing field string information for the field 'l10n_in_hsn_code' from the 'product.template' model

I have tried to check in the databases but I have failed to achieve anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you override the `fields_get` function?

Comment: error: missing field string information for the field 'l10n_in_hsn_code' from the 'product.template' model at https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7386-d7420dd/web.assets_backend.min.js:6629:258

Comment: at traverse (https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7386-d7420dd/web.assets_backend.min.js:6624:200) at https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7386-d7420dd

Comment: web.assets_backend.min.js:6624:242 at function.each (https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7383-9268fa4/web.assets_common.min.js:

Comment: 173:149) at traverse (https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7386-d7420dd/web.assets_backend.min.js:6624:211) at https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7386-d7420dd/web.assets_backend.min.js:6624:242 at function.each (https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7383-9268fa4/web.assets_common.min.js:173:149) at traverse (https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7386-d7420dd/web.assets_backend.min.js:6624:211) at https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7386-d7420dd/web.assets_backend.min.js:6624:242 at function.each (https://uwepo.odoo.co.ug/web/assets/7383-9268fa4/web.assets_common.min.js:173:149)/

Comment: That's the error details though I couldn't post the whole code at once , thanks